# Elasticsearch specific words analysis

Tags: elasticsearch

I have simple question about **Elasticsearch analysis**.

I have full text field in my documents and i want to get from this text just specific words. For example i want to get words *"danger", "error", "warning"* and *"failure"*.

Is there some easy way how to "**cut out**" those words from my text field and store them in index for each document? What should i use for this use case, pattern analyzer or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Pattern Capture Token Filter:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html

Your pattern:
"(danger|error|warning|failure)"

Searching for "danger" would find only documents with "danger" word in the indexed field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this is what i need :)